# Partially string search array of javascript objects for a needle

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using the following

```
haystack = [{'id':'73','name':'Elvis'},{'id':'45','name':'Beatles'}, etc.]
```

I want to perform a search whereby I can find Elvis by searching for "elv" or "Elv" (thus, a case insensitive search). Results should return in array thus allowing more than one needle to be returned from my search.

My solution is convert my needle into lowercase, no spaces, and use a for loop to go thru my haystack making checks on a lowercase/nospace name. But I suspect there are other more resource friendly methods *(I want to know if there is a better way so I can enhance my skillset/knowledge)*

I had thought of using jQuery grep or inArray but both appear to be strict with their comparison. And array.filter() was another idea. But various attempts so far fail.

Thanks

Comment: There's no magic method. Any method is basically going to have to loop through. You could use `haystack.filter(function(o) { return o.name.includes(needle); })`, but again, it's still just a loop underneath.

Comment: ...and `.includes()` is ES2015, so you'd need to patch it for older browsers or use `.indexOf(needle) != -1`

Comment: Thanks - I like your suggested solution as it appears more tidy.

Comment: indexOf though is case sensitive... that won't wash...

Comment: You're welcome. And if you only want to search the start of each `.name`, then use `.startsWith()` instead of `.includes()`.

Comment: I just forgot to convert to lower case since I thought you were already doing that. You can create your own case-insensitive comparison function easily enough, so that the whole word doesn't need to be converted when there's no match..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you tried but `.filter()` should have worked. Make sure to lowercase both the search string and the `name` of the searched items.

```
var searchTerm = 'Elv'.toLowerCase();
var results = haystack.filter(function(item){
    return item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) > -1;
});
```

---

alternatively you could use regexp for the comparison

```
var searchTerm = 'Elv',
    search = new RegExp(searchTerm, 'gi');

var results = haystack.filter(function(item){
    return item.name.match(search);
});
```

Comment: I loved the latter solution with the regular expression. It is neat, tidy and I understand it enough to be able to support it. Lovely!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `Array#filter` and some String's functions

```
var haystack = [{ 'id': '73', 'name': 'Elvis' }, { 'id': '45', 'name': 'Beatles' }];

var w = 'elv';

function search(word) {
    return haystack.filter(function(e) {
        return e.name.toLowerCase().substr(0, word.length) == word;
    });
}

console.log(search(w));
```